# Building a web project for my company using asp.net and having a concern about the storage size of SQL Server Express edition

Tags: sql-server

In my company we have around 850 employees. We are going to build ASP.NET web project to handle many day to day procedures. My question is related to the database MS SQL Server Express which comes with a limit of 10 GB for storage.

How can we esitmate if the 10 GB is enough? And is it easy to upgrade later if we eceeded the limit?

Comment: Have you tried [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/estimate-the-size-of-a-database?view=sql-server-ver16)?

Answer (score 2):

> In my company we have around 850 employees.

Bananas are my favorite fruit.

> We are going to build ASP.NET web project to handle many day to day procedures.

I eat dessert a few times a week.

> My question is related to the database MS SQL Server Express which comes with a limit of 10 GB for storage...How can we esitmate if the 10 GB is enough?

How can my dentist know how many cavities my teeth have?

You have to look at your use cases, your data, and how you plan to use it. Just like my dentist without looking at my teeth, we can't really tell you what your data requirements look like without seeing your data or knowing your use cases.

Best you can do is follow the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/estimate-the-size-of-a-database?view=sql-server-ver16) that mustaccio provided and at least come up with a logical data model with estimates of how many rows you anticipate to have over a given period of time.

Additionally, if your data really is small enough to be close enough to fit within SQL Server Express's data limitations, then you may want to consider if there's a logical partitioning to your data that can be spread across multiple databases on the same SQL Server Express instance. E.g. either by archiving older data in different historical databases, or by some natural key that splits your data accordingly. It would be helpful to you, to proactively implement this kind of design if you were able to.

> And is it easy to upgrade later if we eceeded the limit?

In theory, yes. It should just require purchasing the appropriate license and running the SQL Server installer to apply that license and upgrade the edition accordingly.